# Ionic 4 Arrow Functions

Tags: ionic-framework, alert, arrow-functions, ion-list

I am creating a to do list app with Ionic 4. When the user clicks add a task an alert opens. However when a task is put it the input and the add task button is clicked, nothing happens. I feel like there is an issue with my arrow function but I am not familiar enough with them to spot the problem. I have attached a photo of the bit of code I think is the issue and the link to my github. I would really appreciate feedback and a solution!

[To do list github](https://github.com/Blen6035/HabermanToDO)

[image: Photo of arrow function]

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with the code here:

1. this.tasks = this.taskList.valueChanges();
   This returns an observable so you must use an async pipe to retrieve its value within the template such as:

   *ngFor="let task of tasks | async"
2. The input was set for a different name, the input name here is "title" and that is how the data returned within the arrow function should be referenced as well

```js
async addItem(){
    let addItem = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Add a Task',
      message: 'Please enter a Task',
      inputs: [{
         name: 'title',
         type: 'text'
      }],
      buttons:[{
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel'
      },{
        text: 'Add Task',
        handler: data => {

          let newTaskRef = this.taskList.push(
            { id: '', title: data.title, status: 'open' }
            );
            newTaskRef.update( { id: newTaskRef.key } );

        }
      }]
    })

    await addItem.present();
  }
```

Comment: This now allows the alert to be submitted but the task added is still not appearing in the list. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Have you checked your firebase permissions and database rules?

Comment: These are the rules, should they be set to true instead of false?

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Yeah or you could do:

If you service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Ok I updated the permission to what you said, it is still not updating to the list.

Comment: It appears maybe that you are accessing the database, and not the newer firestore, you may have to check the database rules which are set as this by default:

{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}